# Is there a way to insert an operator into a menu?

Tags: add-on, development

I've written an add-on for saving files, and I want to insert it into the **file>save menu**. But if I use

```
def draw_into_file_menu(self,context):
    self.layout.operator('file.save_n_zip')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(FileSaveAndZip)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file.append(draw_into_file_menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(FileSaveAndZip)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file.remove(draw_into_file_menu)
```

the entry gets added to the bottom of the **file** menu, below **quit** which moves it away from the similar functions.

[image]

Is there a way I can insert it below the other save functions? There's no `insert()` function in `bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file`